# Why recommend "letters, numbers, and special characters" in a User ID?

Tags: authentication, credit-card, financial

Why do some sites recommend "letters, numbers, and special characters" in a username or User ID?

When creating a User ID at the www.discovercard.com website,
the "User ID Strength" indicator meter bar indicates that a User ID is "weak" unless it includes letters, numbers, and special characters.

(It looks similar to the "password strength" indicator bar I see when I change my password).

Comment: I'd speculate they are treating userid like a second factor. Provided it's not revealed to an attacker, the attacker has to guess both your userid and password, thus strengthening auth vs a password alone.

Comment: Some user IDs are better off being private and unguessable - for example I might not want others to know an email user ID that I use (to reduce spam).

Answer (score 9):

User ID are not nominally secret values; that's why we call them "user ID" and not "passwords", and why graphical interfaces for entering them don't hide the characters". However, creative designers sometimes imagine that user ID *are* some kind of secret, which leads to situations like what you witness: a site that tries to enforce on the user ID some "complexity rules" normally applied to passwords.

In practice, user ID *chosen by users* are not very secret, because:

- Interfaces and protocols may leak user ID in various places.
- Users don't consider them secret and thus will not try to make them unguessable.
- Even when users *try* to make things hard to guess (passwords), they usually fail.

However, lack of rationality has never prevented any enthusiastic developer from adding features.

---

Arguably, insistence on including "special characters" in strings is not proven to really make these strings harder to guess. Such so-called complexity rules are meant to force users out of their comfort zone (it works: users are much less happy), under the rather specious assumption that an irate or depressed user will somehow choose passwords which are harder to guess.